# I want to test if a tooltip is present in my ag-grid react column

Tags: jestjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a list of columns in my Ag-grid. I want to test if the tooltip is present in an Ag-grid column. I am using jest in my application. How can we test the tooltip using jest in Ag-grid?

Comment: tooltips in `ag-grid` is configured at each column level by configuring `tooltipField` property, probably checking at column level might help.

Comment: Can you suggest me a way in which we can test them?